# using netty to send several RTSP message

Tags: java, netty, nio, rtsp, rtsp-client

I want to create a RTSP client, to send some RTSP message. I use netty to write this, but my code can only send **one** message. how to send another message?
My client Code like this:

```
public class RtspClient {
    public static class ClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DefaultHttpResponse> {


        @Override
        public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
            ctx.flush();
        }


        protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DefaultHttpResponse msg) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(msg.toString());
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        final ClientHandler handler = new ClientHandler();

        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(workerGroup);
        b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
        b.remoteAddress("127.0.0.1", 8557);
        b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
                ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                p.addLast("encoder", new RtspEncoder());
                p.addLast("decoder", new RtspDecoder());

                p.addLast(handler);
            }
        });

        Channel channel = b.connect().sync().channel();

        DefaultHttpRequest request = new DefaultHttpRequest(RtspVersions.RTSP_1_0, RtspMethods.PLAY, "rtsp:123");
        request.headers().add(RtspHeaderNames.CSEQ, 1);
        request.headers().add(RtspHeaderNames.SESSION, "294");
        channel.writeAndFlush(request);

        Thread.sleep(10000);

         System.out.println(channel.isWritable());
         System.out.println(channel.isActive());
            request = new DefaultHttpRequest(RtspVersions.RTSP_1_0, RtspMethods.TEARDOWN, "rtsp3");
            request.headers().add(RtspHeaderNames.CSEQ, 2);
            request.headers().add(RtspHeaderNames.SESSION, "294");


        }
        channel.writeAndFlush(request);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.nextLine();
        channel.closeFuture().sync();

}
```

this code could only send first message. The server did not receive the second data. how to send another message?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `DefaultFullHttpRequest` or you need to "terminate" each `DefaultHttpRequest` with a `LastHttpContent`.